# iPhone 4 Email Reply Button Missing?

Tags: email, yahoo

I just got this phone yesterday and was checking my yahoo email account. I can read mail from individuals, but he reply/forward/trash buttons are missing from the page?  How can I restore them?

Comment: Could you please link to a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Missing from what page?

At the bottom of an email message, this little arrow is for *Reply, Forward, Print*.

[image: screen capture]